# remove element from linked list at any position in c language

Tags: c, list, linked-list

i have a linked list like this :

1,jhon,19

2,sara,18

3,tom,20

4,jack,22

i have been trying forever to delete an element based on their id (witch is the first number). But in order to do that i need to delete this element  from any position. so i came up with this code and i was wondering if it's correct :

```
            temp1=head;
            if(head!=NULL && head->id==givenID) // if the element is in the first position
            {
                temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                free(temp);
            }
            else if(head!=NULL && head->id!=givenID){// search for the element in the middle
               do{
                  temp2=head;
                  head = head->next;
                  }while(head->id !=givenID && head->next !=NULL);
               if(head->next !=NULL && head->id==givenID){// if the element is in the middle
                    temp2->next=head->next;
                    free(head);
                    head=temp1;
                }
                else if(head->next ==NULL && head->id==givenID){// if the element is in the last position
                 temp->next=NULL;
                 free(head);
                 head=temp1;
                }
              }
```

Thank you

Comment: I thinnk its for code review site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is too complex, because it has unnecessary branches. You can unify your code by using a pointer to pointer.

The idea is to point your pointer to pointer to the `head` of the list, then to the `next` pointer of the initial element of the list, then to the `next` pointer of the second element of the list, and so on. The beauty of this approach is that no matter where you are in your list, the operation on a pointer to pointer remains the same!

Here is how it looks in code:

```
// Point your pointer to pointer to the head of the list
struct node **pptr = &head;
while (*pptr != NULL) {
    // Dereference pptr to get the pointer to current node
    node *current = *pptr;
    // Check if the id of this node matches what we're looking for
    if (current->id == givenID) {
        // Here is the "magic": assign the next pointer of the current node
        // to whatever is pointed to by pptr.
        // It could be a head, or a next of some node.
        *pptr = current->next;
        free(current);
        break;
    }
    pptr = &(current->next);
}
```

That's it! Since the pointer to pointer does not differentiate between head and other nodes, there is no additional checking going on.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a sentry node. All special cases disappear when you do.
This is how node erasure look in a linked list with sentry:

```
Iterator Erase( List* lst, Iterator here )
{
    Iterator nxt = here->next;
    Link( here->prev, here->next ); 
    free( here );
    lst->size -= 1;
    return nxt;
}
```

with Link being no more complicated than

```
void Link( Iterator n1, Iterator n2 )
{
    n1->next = n2;
    n2->prev = n1;
}
```

All the other core functions, like insert etc. are similarly trivial.